# [__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, clgeocoder

This is my code for getting postal code.

```
CLGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
      NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");
      if (error){
          NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
          return;
      }

      NSLog(@"Received placemarks: %@", placemarks);             
      CLPlacemark *myPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *countryCode = myPlacemark.ISOcountryCode;
      NSString *countryName = myPlacemark.country;
      NSLog(@"My country code: %@ and countryName: %@", countryCode, countryName);

}];
```

But its always crashing with `NSInvalidArgumentException` error,

```
2017-02-07 12:29:58.124 CBB[3654:270750] Lat : 42.771389  Long : 

129.423340
2017-02-07 12:29:58.967 CBB[3654:270750] -[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000473b80
2017-02-07 12:29:59.011 CBB[3654:270750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000473b80'
```

Comment: in which line you get this crash

Comment: Check myPlacemark using debug, are you getting exact data what are you expecting?  I think you are having problem in CLPlacemark *myPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];line.

Comment: are you seen this `NSArray *placemarks` ,it reurns array

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes. its getting crash while calling reverse geo code method.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR - in which line you get this crash

Comment: problem s some where else

Comment: myPlacemark.country returns nsdictionary instead of nsstring @PREMKUMAR

Comment: add placemarks and myPlacemark nslog data

Comment: you are calling "bytes" on an object that is actually a nsdictionary. that is the problem. and I dont see any "bytes" method in your pasted code. Pls paste full code.

Answer (score -1):

bytes is NSData's property, so you use NSDictionary as NSData.